# Excel VBA matching record copy data between worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have spent the last week trying to find a solution to this. I'm a total novice in VBA and I need to match a name in column B of worksheet 1 with column A of worksheet 2 and then copy column C of worksheet 1 to the matched row in worksheet 2.

Comment: read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. Basically, show us your current effort to receive some help. Without that, you'll like get no response.

Comment: You've labelled this question as Excel-vba, but to be honest what you're describing sounds more like a VLOOKUP or MATCH/INDEX formula set up. If you're looking at doing something in VBA then post what you've got so far and what's failing and we'll help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without VBA.
In worksheet 2 column C use the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet1!B:C,2,false)
```

Replace `Sheet1` with your sheet name.